# dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0045' near line 0:

Tags: dpkg

I am getting this error in Ubuntu 12.04 , while doing the below operation.

```
frank@august:~$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for frank: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct    the problem. 
frank@august:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0045' near line 0:
 newline in field name `#padding'
frank@august:~$
```

&

```
frank@august:~$ head /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0045
#padding
#padding
#padding
#padding

frank@august:~$
```

I can't see where is the error , help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Ok I have solved the issue myself.

I ran these two commands in terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates && rm -rf 0045
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And my issue was solved.

Comment: Since attempting to run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0045` is safe and proper *but* could have disastrous results if one types in a stray space next to any of the `/`es (especially the first two!), it may be best to warn about this danger or to suggest something like `cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates && rm -rf 0045`. Good solution though!

Comment: In such a situation I'd never use `sudo rm -rf [file]`, but `sudo mv [file] /var/tmp`.

Comment: even with `sudo` access was denied so i had to go to root with `sudo -s` Thanks, this really helped me though once I was in root.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer please?  Like what this does and why it does it?

Comment: What's the difference to @Ten-Coin's ealier answer?

Comment: @KarlRichter Most likely Ten-Coin's answer will not work if your error is not 0045 but other numbers.

Comment: Such a difference doesn't justify a separate answer. You should suggest and improvement to the existing answer instead if the change is so small.

Comment: Its fix my problem on UBUNTU 18.04 LTS with xfce4 desktop.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like the file is corrupted. Suggest you do the following ( pls do take a backup and do it at ur risk ;) )

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/000*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but it didnt helped me http://paste.ubuntu.com/1337768/

Comment: This removes the apparently offending file, but in my case that just got me to the next corrupted file. So I just `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*` and then continues with the clean+update, which worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that status file corrupted,To fix this you have to delete/clear the file using the command.

```
sudo dpkg --clear-status
```

(NB: the --clear-status option is not available anymore.  The printout from 'dpkg -?' does not suggest a clear replacement.
)
then rebuild the file using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```