# problems updating Virtualbox

Tags: updates, virtualbox, dpkg

Something went wrong when I tried to install Virtualbox from 'Software Updater'

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

It looks like the link in 'software updater' to update Virtualbox is http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contib

When I then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  I get this

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0004' near line 5:
missing package name
```

Also 'software updater' reports that "the software index is broken"

I am running Release 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit

I have searched for answers and told to use Synaptic package installer (do not have). Tried with GDebi and get message "only one software update tool allowed to run at one time" (nothing else is running)

Help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0045' near line 0:](http://askubuntu.com/questions/213460/dpkg-error-parsing-file-var-lib-dpkg-updates-0045-near-line-0)