# When I try to install ufw it says this

Tags: error-handling

I type `sudo apt install ufw` then is says:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I write `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then It says:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006' near line 0:
 newline in field name '#padding'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove problematic file with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006
```

and then retry

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I tried to write  sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006 but it said rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006': No such file or directory

Comment: I did this https://askubuntu.com/a/213738/1195405   and it works